# Event Store in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, event-sourcing

We are running an event sourced system in Microsoft Azure.
The system uses SQL Azure for persistence. There is one table were we frequently insert a lot of data, sometimes with a payload up to 20k.

Then there is a worker, which periodically fetches the latest data from the table for processing.
It uses the identity column, to fetch the next 512 entries ahead of the previously read.

We have seen that during intensive workloads, it occasionally skips entries.
As if certain rows are made available before rows with lower identity value.
We haven't had this problem running a regular on site SQL Server, but in Azure SQL we periodically see this problem.

What available options are there, except changing event store persistence solution?

Comment: Github repo with simple example code reproducing the same behavior https://github.com/adamfur/AzureSqlInsertSequence

Comment: Made a workaround https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore.Persistence.SQL/issues/14  . Personally I think it's a bug in SQL Azure.